# Marking questions as duplicate is ruining reputation rise in general

Tags: discussion, reputation, duplicate-questions

This is a deeper concept than it appears to be. Reputation of newbies on Stack Overflow almost never grows.

The day-to-day (regular) problems that a person faces in programming are already answered on Stack Overflow. Too often, I find a question which is being marked as duplicate. In this case, how am I supposed to improve my reputation with no new questions to answer?

If there are no new questions, no new answers, no rise in reputation.
Reputation of a newbie is almost saturated.

Shouldn't we consider cleaning the Stack Overflow database at least once in 5 years so that questions can be taken in as all new?

Comment: Invalidating good, existing questions simply to allow new people to answer identical questions is idiotic and runs utterly counter to how SE is supposed to work. You don't simply go to an old Wikipedia page and delete it to create a new one just so that someone else can write it.  If you want to answer questions, go to the original question and see if you can add another point of view rather than asking SE to delete old, **USEFUL** questions.

Comment: @Catija Wikipedia cannot be compared with StackExchange.Life on stack exchange is highly dependent on reputation.But wikipedia has no such reputation or levels.

Comment: There is still absolutely zero reason to delete good content.

Comment: @Catija That was just a suggestion.And stackoverful would become less dynamic in the coming years with no questions remaining at all..

Comment: I dispute the claim that such a large percentage of questions being closed that it is impossible to gain reputation. Also, I agree with what @Catija says.

Comment: It's like you think that programming is going to come to some point of stasis where no new methods exist... which is silly.  People will always have new questions.

Comment: @Catija users with reputation above 3000 wouldn't undersatnd.High reputation often helps in earning reputation.I have seen better answers given by newbies being upvoted less as compared to an answer given by a high reputed user.We need an urgent 'reputation feed'.Either throw it all,auction it or sell it.Life on SE with low reputation is horrible.

Comment: @MathewsMathai All users have been there. None of us started with anything but one reputation point. We understand what it's like to be a new guy.

Comment: @HDE 226868 Something new is required.Well,I know that you all have faced this situation at some point in the past.

Comment: Do you realize how your last suggestions is completely contrary to what these sites are for, i.e. repositories of knowledge in Q&A form? SO's not a game. Gaining rep isn't one of the goals.

Comment: I think a better solution would be have some mechanism to gain reputation by finding duplicates and by making improvements to existing content.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, finding questions that are closed as a duplicate prevents YOU from answering that question which would enable you to gain reputation. Assuming your answer is good enough to receive up votes that is.

However, having duplicates point to each other is one great way to direct future visitors to the question that has answers that will help those users. Being able to have links between questions and makeing sure that duplicate questions point to a single canonical post is the best way to organize knowledge and be a quality repository of Q/A's.

You seem to suggest that you can only answer new questions. That is a little bit strange given the fact that there are almost [3,000](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython-3.x%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano) questions in your top tag that don't have an answer and are not closed. Those questions also are waiting for an answer.

Don't make the mistake that the sites within the SE network exist to let its users gain reputation. Nobody will visit a site to see how a user gains Imaginary Internet Points. You'll get visits if you offer a knowledge base that is moderated into quality which is what we do here.

Your last proposal is to delete all content once every 5 years and start anew. Again that will be an inmense waste of knowledge, made available to and used by millions of visitors.

I suggest to focus on content.  Try to work-out how the content you post will be of value for other users. That should be your one and only goal. If you do that well the reputation will come. Be patient.